# Where to CATCH an EXCEPTION thrown within an EVAL

Tags: javascript, ajax, eval

The following script enables you to run a piece of javascript code. Errors are being catched by the try / catch block.

```
    try {
        var result = eval(script);
    } catch (e) {
        // do something meaningful
    }
```

However, if the variable `script` contains for instance an AJAX call, and this ajax call throws an exception (e.g. in the success function), this exception will NOT be catched by this try / catch block...

```
    // execute an AJAX request
        var script = '$.ajax(url:"/somewhere", success: function(){throw new MyException('testexception')})';
    try {
        var result = eval(script);
    } catch (e) {
        // will not be triggered...
    }
```

**Question**: how can I catch the exception thrown within the ajax request?

Comment: Aside from not using `eval` at all, even if you weren't using it and you had that function inside a `try/catch` block, it wouldn't catch an exception from the `success` function because it's a callback. That code won't be called until after you've exited your `try/catch`

Comment: Isn't this about adding an error callback in the ajax request?

Comment: @MattBurland 100% agreed - but that is my question...

Comment: @Huangism no. don't think so.

Comment: Well the short answer is that you'd have to catch an exception in the callback *in the callback*

Comment: try to add to ajax async:false

Comment: jQuery has deprecated `async: false`. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @MattBurland okay, Matt... Thanks for your help!

Comment: @itsame69 See my answer below for one perspective on dealing with this issue.

Comment: @Dani/Jacob Sorry, but this is not a solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I hope you are aware of the dangers of using `eval`, and if not there are plenty of good articles out there that explain why it is not a good idea.

That being said, the issue is that the success callback is being called after the catch block. You'll need to either add the `try/catch` block within the success callback, or you'll need to handle the error from a more global perspective. One idea I can think of to do this is using the [window.onerror](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror#window.onerror) event. I have an example below that shows something similar to your problem, and one that shows you can catch errors thrown in `eval`.

```js
(function() {

  'use strict';

  window.addEventListener('error', e => console.log(`window.onerror: ${e.message}`));

  let script = `setTimeout(function() {
    throw new Error('Whoops!');
  }, 0);`;

  eval(script);

  script = `throw new Error('Whoops!');`;

  try {
    eval(script);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  }

})();
```